# How to create dynamic progress bar on asynchronous post back in asp.net (Not gif image)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, progress-bar

How can I show a dynamic progress bar on my asp.net page on asynchronous post back. My code takes lot of time so I want to show percentage on that progress bar like following

[image]

I googled this but I found code that can show only gif image. Please suggest me.

Comment: check this :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/646535/A-More-Efficient-AJAX-Progress-Bar-for-ASP-NET

Comment: See the questions under "Related" to the right.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jquery see this example: https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#default.

You can set the value property to the desired percentage value